# How do I integrate Nest.js and MongoDB inside a Docker container?

Tags: mongodb, docker, nestjs, typeorm

## Issue:

TypeORM in Nest.js can't authenticate with MongoDB inside Docker Container

## Sample Code:

- docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  mongodb:
    container_name: rosie-mongodb-1
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ###REDACTED FOR SECURITY###
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ###REDACTED FOR SECURITY###
      MONGODB_DATABASE: "rosie"
    networks:
      - rosie-net

  nest-backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/usr/src/app
    networks:
      - rosie-net


# Rest of File
```

- app.module.ts:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';
import { EntitiesModule } from './entities/entities.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mongodb',
      url: 'mongodb://###REDACTED FOR SECURITY###:###REDACTED FOR SECURITY###@mongodb:27017/rosie',
      synchronize: true,
    }),
    EntitiesModule,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private dataSource: DataSource) {}
}
```

## Authentication Errors In MongoContainer:

```
Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)...
2023-08-07 19:36:55 MongoServerError: Authentication failed.
2023-08-07 19:36:55     at Connection.onMessage (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/src/cmap/connection.ts:413:18)
2023-08-07 19:36:55     at MessageStream.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/src/cmap/connection.ts:243:56)
2023-08-07 19:36:55     at MessageStream.emit (node:events:513:28)
2023-08-07 19:36:55     at processIncomingData (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/src/cmap/message_stream.ts:193:12)
2023-08-07 19:36:55     at MessageStream._write (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/src/cmap/message_stream.ts:74:5)
2023-08-07 19:36:55     at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:392:12)
2023-08-07 19:36:55     at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:333:10)
2023-08-07 19:36:55     at MessageStream.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:337:10)
2023-08-07 19:36:55     at Socket.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:766:22)
2023-08-07 19:36:55     at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
```

I've tried setting the authentication in separate variables like below:

```
imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mongodb',
      host: '###REDACTED###',
      port: 27017,
      username: '###REDACTED###',
      password: '###REDACTED###',
      database: 'rosie',
      synchronize: true,
    }),
    EntitiesModule,
  ],
```

I've also tried setting them in a uri string as well.

I've tested the authentication through MongoDB Compass and it works.

I've rebuilt and restarted the containers multiple times to ensure changes were saved.

Comment: Are you running the Nest server inside the same docker-compose project?

Comment: Yes I am. Nest is in a container as well as mongodb. Let me update the docker-compose above

Answer (score 0):

After constant methods of retrying. I went back to read the MongoDB logs and noticed the entry:

```
2023-08-07 21:23:48 {"t":{"$date":"2023-08-08T02:23:48.677+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":20249,   "ctx":"conn48","msg":"Authentication failed","attr":{"mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-1","speculative":false,"principalName":"rosie","authenticationDatabase":"rosie","remote":"###REDACTED###","extraInfo":{},"error":"UserNotFound: Could not find user \"###REDACTED###\" for db \"rosie\""}}
```

**Solution:**
My error was due to not creating the user on the correct database